# How to access a computer file on a phone

Tags: ios, swift

I am using

```
let data = try? 
NSString(contentsOfFile: "/Users/BenA**** 1/Desktop/textFile.txt", 
encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

to access a file on my computer.  When I test put the app on my phone, it obviously didn't work because it didn't have access to the file.  How could I put this file on my phone and be able to access it from there?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include your "textFile.txt" in main bundle by drag and drop file in to xcode project, then access it by

```
class testViewController: UIViewController{

var data:String = ""
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("textFile", ofType: "txt")
    data = try? NSString(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: ENCODING)
}}
```

Try this way to access 'data' in rest of code.
Hope this help.

Comment: I replaced my previous code with this, and I get: Cannot use instance member 'path' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available.  Putting it in the viewDidLoad function fixed the error, but the variable wasn't accessible by the rest of the code.  Getting rid of the path variable and just putting in the path worked, though.

Answer (score 0):

To simulate the behavior of iOS enable the sandbox on macOS.

Now you can access files only in the **container** of the app.

Nevertheless the predefined folders like `Documents`, `Library` etc. still exist.

To have access to that directories there a method of `NSFileManager`. For example one of the most important directories in iOS is the `Documents` directory.

```
let documentsFolderURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask).first!
```

You have to use that method each time you need to get the URL of that particular directory because for security reasons the absolute path will change.